# Show that $\text{trace}(A^TA) \ge 0$ and $\text{trace}(A^TA)$ if and only if $A = O$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, transpose

## Problem

Show that $\text{trace}(A^TA) \ge 0$ and $\text{trace}(A^TA)=0$ if and only if $A = O$ when $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Symbol $O$ denotes zero matrix.

## Attempt to show

I think I know intuitively this is right but how to prove this? I could show some example but unfortunately, this won't exactly prove anything. The problem is how to approach this proof?

Comment: Please clarify the second statement

Comment: Can you try to write an explicit formula for $Tr(A^TA)$ in terms of the coefficients of $A$ ?

Comment: @G.Chiusole What you mean by this exactly?

Comment: **.....and trace...** ---its incomplete

Comment: @Tuki what is the second statement? Doy ou mean $\text{trace}(A^TA)=0$ if and only if $A = 0$?

Comment: The wording is confusing. Do you mean: "Show for any $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$, $n \in \Bbb N$ that (1) $\operatorname{trace}(A^T A) \geq 0$ and (2) $\operatorname{trace}(A^T A) = 0$ if and only if $A = O$."?

Comment: @G.Chiusole sorry, it should be fixed now

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154750/prove-that-traceata-0-if-and-only-if-a-0?rq=1)

Comment: @Travis Yes exactly this was my intention. The wording could be better indeed

Comment: By the way, linearity of trace shows that $\operatorname{trace}((\alpha A)^T (\alpha A)) \geq \alpha^2 \operatorname{trace}(A^T A)$, which together with the result of the exercise shows that $A \mapsto \sqrt{\operatorname{trace}(A^T A)}$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$---this is the **Frobenius norm**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $\bf{A^{t}A}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix