# Help with reasoning for $\operatorname{tr}(D^2) = 0 \implies D = 0$ where D is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, diagonalization, trace

I have the following for  $\operatorname{tr}(D^2) = 0 \implies D = 0$

If $D = 0$, clearly $\operatorname{tr}(D^2) = 0$.
If $D \ne 0$, it has entries on the diagonal, which, when squared, must be greater than $0$. Then the trace of the squared matrix must be greater than $0$ by definition of the trace, which is a contradiction to the premise that $\operatorname{tr}(D^2) = 0$, hence $D = 0$. Is this correct reasoning, and if so, is there a better way to show this than writing all this out?

Edit: Forgot to mention that D is a diagonal matrix

Comment: What is $D$ exactly?

Comment: If your $D$ is restricted to real diagonal matrices then your reasoning is ok, but the statement is false in general (consider $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$)

Comment: Ah I see I forgot to mention D is a diagonal matrix

Answer (score 7):

A counterexample is the identity matrix $D=I_2\in GL(2,\Bbb F_2)$, where $D^2=D$ has trace $2=0$, but $D\neq 0$. Over the complex numbers consider
$$
D=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & i \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then the trace of $D^2$ is zero, but $D$ is nonzero. Over a field of arbitrary characteristic, consider
$$
D=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Is it possible that your question is meant to be the following popular question
[Prove that $\operatorname{trace}(A^TA) = 0\ \iff\ A = 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154750/prove-that-operatornametraceata-0-iff-a-0) ?

Comment: I don't think characteristic 0 is necessary.

Comment: Would my reasoning work if the entries of D were only real?

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you, edited.

Comment: No, the matrix $D=(1,1,-1,1)$ has only real entries. For diagonal real matrices, $a_1^2+\cdots +a_n^2=0$ implies indeed that all $a_i$ are zero.

Comment: Assuming $0$ characteristic, the result is true for *symmetric* matrices. A way to see this is that $\textrm{Trace}\left(A^{T}A\right)$ is positive definite (in fact, it's a scalar product). For $\mathbb{C}$ the result is true for the corresponding generalisation of the scalar product, which is $\textrm{Trace}\left(A^{\dagger}A\right)$. So it's true for Hermitian matrices. I'm talking finite matrices and just $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, of course.